# Static const variable in each subclass

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, static, constants

I am currently building an interface for SQL database tables. My current class hierarchy looks like that, listed with some basic methods and variables:

```
class AbstractTable
{
public:
    AbstractTable(QString tableName);
    void addRow(); // it operates on tableName and colNames
private:
    const QString tableName;
    const QStringList colNames;
    //... some more, for example:
    const QString identificationCollumn;
}

class ProductsTable : public AbstractTable
{
    ProductsTable();
}

class UsersTable: public AbstractTable
{
    UsersTable();
}
```

The point is, `AbstractTable::tableName` and `AbstractTable::colNames` are initialized during the object creation, and it is set at a particular `xxxTable` constructor. There are also some other const variables.

Now, my Tables have a lot of instances across the program(and I can't reduce it, as some features are context-based), and I would like to reduce the redundancy present in my code. The first thought that came into my mind is to make both `AbstractTable::tableName` and `AbstractTable::colNames` static, but it would introduce only a single field for all classes(I need a field for each subclass type). I would have to remove the `tableName` and `colNames` initialization from `AbstractTable` and move it to all the classes that inherit from `AbstractTable` - then I would be able to mark it `static`. It doesn't really solve the problem, as a method `addRow` should be able to operate on `tableName` and `colNames`. It could be solved by making a virtual method `virtual QString AbstractTable::getTableName()`, which would be implemented in each subclass (i.e. `ProductsTable::getTableName()` would return a static field with value "products"). But the next point shows why it is not a solution:

Finally, I would want to make method `addRow()` static for each of the tables, so a call to `ProductsTable::addRow()` would add a row to a table named `Products`, which seems to be necessary to implement in each child class, which would produce a lot of copy-paste to each subclass.

It looks like I have to move all the fields to subclass, leaving parent class pointless. `tableName`, and `colNames` would have to be implemented in subclasses, even though these variables would be the same in each subclass, `addRow()` need to be moved to subclass, because a call to i.e. `ProductsTable::addRow()` need to add row to `Products`, while `UsersTable::addRow()` need to add row to users.

The point of `tableName` and `colNames` is to let the abstract class work. So I can have implemented an instruction `q.exec("SELECT ("+colNames.join(',')+") FROM "+tableName);`, a solution which would make implementing `addRow` logic in each subclass makes my whole structure pointless, as `ProductsTable::select()`, could just call `q.exec("SELECT (a,b,c,d,e) FROM Products");` - since colNames and tableName is constant.

Is there a way to solve this problem in C++ while keeping the parent class implementations, as it is common for all subclasses?

Comment: I dont understand the design. Do you really need `ProductsTable` and `UsersTable` as subclasses, or are they perhaps just instances of `AbstractTable` with different values for `tableName`, `colNames`, etc. ? Your subclasses seem to add nothing to the `AbstractTable` other than wanting to have different values for static members, when you instead create different instances of `AbstractTable` the problem is not present

Comment: If you're concerned about the tiny amount of memory used by each class instance just change `tableName` from `QString` which stores its value by copying to something which doesn't like `const char*`, `std::string_view` or `QstringView` then store the actual value in a static in the child classes

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number In my design it is necessary to introduce productsTable and usersTable as subclasses, as I have to format incoming messages differently, for example my product mass has to be expressed in `g` so if I get `kg`, I have to change unit to `g` and multiply `mass` by 1000, then call addRow while users table don't need that much work with formatting.

Comment: I am not really understanding your initial issue to begin with: What is the issue with passing `tableName` and `colNames` to a (to-be-written) `AbstractTable(tableName, colNames)` ctor? This can either be done from a subclass-ctor or when creating a `AbstractTable` instance as @463035818_is_not_a_number points out (which i believe to be the better solution tbh).

Comment: @Lidbey In that case, a second class would even be better! E.g a `TableFormatter` or whatever you wanna call it. You could even pass that to the `AbstractTable` ctor as well. From my intuitive understanding I wouldn't expect a class named `AbstractTable` class to do anything else than **basic** SQL operations and glue code.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann the initial issue is with memory, I do have some context-based variables (for example 100 devices need to access whole database, by that I mean call `SELECT * from tableName`, and each can work at their own speed with data from `q.next()` (A table can have million rows so I wouldn't like to store that big of an array), that's why context-based(example 100 instances of `products` table) is also necessary in my design, I find it pointless to store 100 times `tableName`

Comment: @Lidbey Ah, now i believe to understand. In that case, split instance-specific behaviour and common behaviour in two classes, e.g. a `TableDescriptor` object holding ``tableName` and `colNames` (one instance per SQL table) and a `TableCursor` holding the fetched data (multiple instances)

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Do you mean splitting the variables and methods that I wanted to make `static`(atomic ones) to different class than the variables and methods that are context-specific(not atomic). That's actually a point of my question, what should the structure look like, if I want to keep `addRow()` method implementation common for each subclass, just with the usage of different `tableName` and `colNames`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do is to split the instance-specific behavior and the behavior shared by all instances into two classes, i.e. to introduce an additional indirection.

```
struct TableDescriptor {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> cols;
};

class AbstractTable {
protected:
    AbstractTable(const TableDescriptor& descriptor)
        : descriptor(descriptor) 
    {
        // Feel free to change to your prefered way of storing refs if you feel uncomfortable with storing const refs
        // e.g shared_ptr or theirlike
        // if you want to modify the descriptor here, just pass a regular reference an not a const ref
    }

private:
    const TableDescriptor& descriptor;  // 8 bytes per instance on x64
};

class UserTable : public AbstractTable {
    static TableDescriptor user_desc;

public:
    UserTable()
        : AbstractTable(user_desc)
    {
    }
};

TableDescriptor UserTable::user_desc{"user_table", {"id", "name"}};
```

If each table has some common rows, they can be added automatically in the `TableDescriptor` ctor to prevent unnecessary copy-pasting.

Comment: At the beginning I would like to thank You as it is a great solution. I would only ask: as it was stated in my question, to make `ProductsTable::addRow(PARAMETERS)` work, it is necessary to introduce `static AbstractTable::addRow(TableDescriptor& descriptor, PARAMETERS)` and make `ProductsTable::addRow(PARAMETERS)` call Abstract one with its static descriptor. It is also possible to call `AbstractTable::addRow(ProductsTable::descriptor, PARAMETERS)` without the need to implement additional methods. Is there a way calling `ProductsTable::addRow()` be implemented only in `AbstractTable`?

Comment: @Lidbey If you want a method for modifying the `TableDescriptor` then the most suiting place would be a regular method in `TableDescriptor`, i.e. `TableDescriptor::addRow()` (this can be virtual if you want to). I don't fully understand your question, especially the last part: `without the need to implement additional methods.` -> then only implement a regular method in `AbstractTable`? If the question is actually about end-user API: You are of course free to expose the `TableDescriptor` from `AbstractTable`. If you only want to expose certain methods, consider exposing a "Proxy" object.